# dbms_output.put_line make newline from input parameter?

Tags: sql, oracle

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('cost: '||' '||test_pkg.F_test(1,'USA')||' '||'Dollar');

output: USA 1,40

But i want the outprint to be like this:

Country: USA

Val: 1,40

How can i achive this?

Comment: Your output doesn't appear to match the contents of the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`. Could you please update your question to produce the actual output that you get along with the expected output?

Comment: Just call put_line twice, once for each line. (this is why it's called "put_line" instead of just "put").

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating CHR(10)

```
select 'd'||chr(10)||'l' from dual;

'D'||CHR(10)||'L'
-----------------
d                 
l
```